# How to use Codeception Acceptance Helper?

Tags: php, testing, joomla, codeception

I'm trying to login to Joomla backend before all tests in my Cest Class.

I'm using the Joomla Browser Module for that:
https://github.com/joomla-projects/joomla-browser

When using it inside the cest class the login gets performed before every test, which is not wanted:

```
public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->doAdministratorLogin();    
}
```

When adding it to the Acceptance Helper like this:

```
namespace Helper;

class Acceptance extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function _beforeSuite($settings = array()) {
        $I = $this;
        $I->doAdministratorLogin();    
    }
}
```

I get

> Call to undefined method Helper\Acceptance::doAdministratorLogin()

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve JoomlaBrowser module:

```
$this->getModule('JoomlaBrowser')->doAdministratorLogin();
```

Also you used `_before` method in Cest file, but `_beforeSuite` in Helper file.
WebDriver object is not initialized in _beforeSuite.

Your options are:

1. move that code to `_before`
2. call `_initialize` method in `_beforeSuite`

   $this->getModule('JoomlaBrowser')->_initialize();
   $this->getModule('JoomlaBrowser')->doAdministratorLogin();

Comment: i get this `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
 Call to a member function get() on null`

Comment: Please run codeception with `-vvv` flag and show us the stack trace.

Comment: webDriver is not initialized yet in `_beforeSuite` method. Move that code to `_before`.

Comment: what should i move where ??

Comment: maybe you can add that to your answer?